# Troubleshot refiner gibberish

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, refiner

I have a managed metadata column in a library, then our admin map it to a crawled property in Central Admin and ran a full crawl.

When I add the refinable property to Refiner, I saw the gibberish as below:

[image: refiner gibberish]

I wonder how can I troubleshot the refiner gibberish?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mapped the managed property with the crawled property that contains **taxId** in its name.

[image: Wrong mapping]

You'll have to remap the managed property with another crawled property that does not contain the **taxId** in its name. You should normally have two of them as you can see in the screenshot above. The crawled property without the taxId contains only the display name.

Comment: Thank you that solve my problem entirely.
BTW what is taxId then and why would we have two of those?

Comment: The crawled property with taxId contains the ID of the term. By default this property gets used with the auto-created managed property and that property consists of the label and id. Using the label value is better for working with refiners, otherwise it could be that your URLs get to large.